# Meteor Google Analytics: setting

Tags: meteor, google-analytics

I am using mup to deploy my app to production server and I'd like to know if I am setting things up correctly. I deployed my website about an hour ago but Google Analytics still says "Tracking is not installed yet".

This is what I have right now.

I installed the meteor google-analytics package

`meteor add datariot:ganalytics`

and in mup setting.json

```
{
  "public" : {
    "ga": {
      "account":"UA-45555555-5"
    }
  }
}
```

In router, I am logging a few events

```
Router.route('/', function () {
  GAnalytics.pageview();
  this.render('Main', {
    to: 'content'
  });
});

Router.route('/about', function () {
  GAnalytics.pageview("/about");
  this.render('About', {
    to: 'content'
  });
});
```

I have no idea why Google Analytics is not tracking my website. Does it require more time to load up?

**EDIT:** I continued debugging GA integration into my app. I installed GA debugger chrome extension, and the meteor package for GA seems to send events correctly. However, I can't see anything on the report or the realtime dashboard. If I use the tracking code provided by Google instead, I can see myself on the realtime dashboard but it sends pageview events only when I refresh a page. I put the tracking code in `Template.Layout.rendered`

```
  Template.Layout.rendered = function() {
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-123456795-5', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
  }
```

Comment: Always check your real time reports because it takes time for the GA data to be processed. Make sure you aren't filtering your visits either. Also you can install GA debugger to check.

Comment: I don't think it took a long time for it to register with GA when I set it up. Also, I'd put the call to pageview in an iron router onRun block which is guaranteed to run once per page. Otherwise you can have issues of counting each page view multiple times

Comment: did you use Meteor packages for GA or just the code provided by Google?

Answer (score 2):

I ended up including the tracking code provided by Google inside my `layout.html` template, and sending pageviews manually by including

```
GARecordPage = function(pageLocation) {
  ga('create', 'UA-12312323-5', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview', {
    page: pageLocation
  });
}
```

inside a `globals.js`

and using it inside `router.js` for every page that I wanted to track:

```
Router.route('/', function () {
  GARecordPage('/');
  this.render('Main', {
    to: 'content'
  });
});
```

It works great and you also get the `realtime` dashboard working well. When I used the Metoer packages the realtime dashboard wasn't working for some reason.

Comment: Hey, I'm using google analytics traking but the real time isnt working on mobile devices with native app installed. Can you help me?